# PHP Change Span Id Inner Html using Java

Tags: javascript, php, echo

I am trying to change a span id inner html text from `php echo` statement.For this I have written below code but it is giving a syntex error in `document.getElementById` line

```
if ($con->query("SELECT question_id FROM saved_questions WHERE question_id='".$quiz_question['id']."' and user_id='".$this->session->userdata('user_id')."'")->num_rows > 0) 
{
  echo ('
   <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
      document.getElementById("btn-save'".$quiz_question['id']."'").innerHTML="newtext"; //syntex error in this line
   </SCRIPT>');

}
```

what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to remove `echo` and use plain output:

```
if ($con->query("SELECT question_id FROM saved_questions WHERE question_id='".$quiz_question['id']."' and user_id='".$this->session->userdata('user_id')."'")->num_rows > 0) 
{?>
   <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
      document.getElementById("btn-save<?php echo $quiz_question['id']?>").innerHTML="newtext";
   </SCRIPT>
<?php
}
```